# Is Reflection allowed within EJBs?

Tags: reflection, ejb, ejb-3.0, ejb-3.1, ejb-3.2

I am wondering, which portions of reflection are allowed to be used within EJBs (EJB3.x), which ones are discouraged to be used and which ones are forbidden.

[EDIT] I am generally speaking about stuff like getMethod(), method.invoke() etc on the different EJB Types, so no java POJO stuff.

I searched the EJB core specification without finding real hints on that.

I personally believe, that avoiding the use of reflection outside frameworks is good programming style, but the question remains, which portions are allowed by standard?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question is not specific. Under what context within EJB? Cause third party libraries used within ejb session beans may use reflections. But performing a reflective call on ejb session beans itself wouldnt be a good idea of course, cause how ejb container provides a reference to a bean is implementation dependent, some using proxy, some inheriting from your own session bean

Comment: thanks for the hint, I specified my question a little more. I mean using reflection on EJB types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you seen what spec EJB 3.1 says in point 21.2.2 ?

> The enterprise bean must not attempt to query a class to obtain information about the declared
>   members that are not otherwise accessible to the enterprise bean because of the security rules
>   of the Java language. The enterprise bean must not attempt to use the Reflection API to access
>   information that the security rules of the Java programming language make unavailable.

So generally speaking - you should not violate language defined security rules.

Comment: I found that one. I once learned, that using reflection in general is forbidden on EJBs, but that is not covered. This implies that a method.invoke() on an EJB proxy would be OK as long as the method is public, right?